# How do I use active directory for authentication and ASP.NET identity in MVC 5 for roles when running on IIS and using code first?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I could really use some help. I'm newer to C# and ASP.Net MVC 5. I currently have an internal website that I've build that will run on IIS. The final component I need to work out is authorization. This has been surprisingly hard to find. The biggest issue I have found is that Microsoft has changed the way to handle this multiple times. It appears to me that membership, universal membership, and simple membership are no longer used and the way to do things now is with Identity. As I didn't know what I was looking for  at first I looked into all of these at least some as I was under the impression that identity was a .Net Core thing. All of the blog posts and tutorials seems to deal with outside web sites that the user would log into. That isn't what I need. Also, most of the answers are really old, so I'm not sure if this is the modern way of doing things.

My shop currently uses ASP.NET MVC 5 (not core) and we have on premise active directory (AD). What I want to accomplish is to have all AD users have access to the site. Then have a page where I can grant select users admin privileges so they can manage their staff. I'm currently using a code first approach with Entity framework, which I'm also new to. I had planned to use the `[Authorize]` attribute to accomplish this, but again, I'm a bit lost in what I need to do to hook this all up.

So my questions is: Using code first with Entity Framework, how can I use AD for my authentication and Identity for my authorization when my site will run on IIS? Also, should I be using Identity?

My roles will be pretty simple. Probably Admin and Manager. Admin will have access over everything, Manager will have access over there section.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You can use ad groups such as Admin Manager and then use isMemberOf these groups to control what level of access the user can see.

Comment: AD groups won't be a great solution here. The person who will manage the users does not have access to AD and I don't want to have to change an AD group every time someone needs to gain or lose access.

Comment: Do you have a database attached, you could use a SQL or similar to control access?

Comment: I will be using a SQL database. Since I'm using code first with Entity Framework, I was hoping to utilize the `[Authorize]` Attribute on the controller to secure access. How would I use what your suggesting?

Comment: Simply have a users login table and set a role in the table, when they login, have a look in the table then set the access in your controller. You could then create a class in the Global then decorate your controller like [Authorise] with the level of access